# Satisfying a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration, derivatives

[image: question]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/5d1ed159ca9ead7e71709109aa1c70a7.png?1360107251))</sub>

So, $y=2cos(kt)$
Therefore, $y'=-2sin(kt)k$
Thus, $y''=-2cos(kt)k^2$

Plugging this into $4y'' = -16y$ ...

$4(-2cos(kt)k^2)=-16(2cos(kt))$

I've simplified it this far:

$(cos(k)k^2+4cos(k))=0$

What next ?

Comment: You have a sign error in the last line, and dropped the "$t$" when you shouldn't have. The correct equation is $k^2\cos (kt)-4\cos(kt)=0$; or, $(k^2-4)\cos(kt)=0$. So, what is $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's next?  Just some trig/algebra.

Factor out $\cos(kt)$:
$$\left(\cos(kt)\right)\left(k^2 - 4\right)=0$$

Now, the expression will be zero whenever either of the two factors are zero.

I think you should be able to take it from here...