# Differential Equation $4y''=-25y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A) For what values of $k$ does the function $y=cos(kt)$ satisfy the differential equation $4y'' = -25y$?

This is what I have:

*You may assume that I derived everything correctly.

$\mathbf{L.H.S} = -4(k^2\cos(kt) = -(2k)^2\cos(kt) = -(2k)^2y \implies k= \pm \frac{5}{2}$.

B) For those values of $k$, verify that every member of the family of functions $y=A\sin(kt) + B\cos(kt)$ is also a solution.

This is what I have:

$\mathbf{L.H.S} = -4k^2(A\sin(kt) + B\cos(kt)) = -(2k)^2y \implies k= \pm \frac{5}{2}.$

Therefore, I have verified the equation etc...

Did I do this right? I'm more interested in the format and 'way' I've done it.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Yeah you got it

Comment: Closely related: [For what values of $k$ does the function $y=2\cos(kt)$ satisfy the differential equation $4y''=-16y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295877/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%244y%27%27%3D-25y%24&p=1)*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are interested in the presentation. Let me propose you another:

What I would do:

If $\cos{(kt)}$ is a solution of the diff. eq. in question the equation that must be verified is then

$$4k^2\cos{(kt)} = 25\cos{(kt)}$$

Rearranging the latter equation
$$(4k^2-25)\cos{(kt)}=0$$
must be true for all $t$, and therefore $4k^2-25=0$, equation from which one can obtain the two values for $k$.

For the second question:

If $\cos{(kt})$ is a solution for those obtained values of $k$, it is obvious that any constant multiplied by such a solution is also a solution and $A\cos{(kt})$ is also a solution.

For the function $B\sin{(kt)}$ we can argue that since 
$$\sin{(kt}) = \cos{(kt-\tfrac{\pi}{2})}$$ 
and we can choose the origin of time arbitrarily, choosing the origin of time $t_0 = \tfrac{\pi}{2k}$ we can assert that the solution 
$$B\sin{(kt}) = B\cos{(kt-\tfrac{\pi}{2})}=B\cos{[k(t-\tfrac{\pi}{2k})]}$$ 
is also a solution that is shifted in time.

This is not required but is a direct consequence:

From this result that the most compact general solution of such an equation is 
$$y=A\cos{(kt+\phi_0)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of these solutions look correct. There are ways of explicitly solving the question, but those would be taught in higher level differential equations courses. Your method of carrying out the differentiation and then comparing the LHS and RHS is valid.

For part b, you do more than the question requests. You could have simply started off by substituting in the values of k, rather than solving for k. This would have saved you a step in the end, but your answer is entirely valid as well.